# Sort column circular dependency in Power BI

Tags: sorting, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, circular-dependency

I have to sort month name from January to December in Power BI Desktop.
Power BI sorts the column according to the alphabetical order.

Here is my dataset:
[image: Data-set]

When I am using sort by column by month number, I am getting an error of circular dependence:

> [image: Error message]

There is no date table in my dataset. I have calculated month number as calculated column.

How can I get rid of this circular dependency? This is the desired result:
[image: Final result]

Comment: I know in Excel you can enable a setting to allow Circular references, https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/12/15/circular-reference-excel/ See if you can do the same

Comment: It's not happening even after enabling the circular reference in Excel file.

Answer (score 6):

The sort column **doesn't work** if created like this:

[image: sort order circular dependency power bi 1]

---

### It works if created like this:

[image: sort order circular dependency power bi 2]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the power query editor and duplicate the Month column and then create a new step using the following code:

```
= let
   Source = #"Previous Step Name",
   Substitutions = [
   #"January" = "1",
   #"February" = "2",
   #"March" = "3",
   #"April" = "4",
   #"May" = "5",
   #"June" = "6",
   #"July" = "7",
   #"August" = "8",
   #"September" = "9",
   #"October" = "10",
   #"November" = "11",
   #"December" = "12"],
   Substituted = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Duplicate Month Column", each Record.FieldOrDefault(Substitutions, _, _)}})
in
   Substituted
```

Remember to replace the **Previous Step Name** and **Duplicate Month Column** for the corresponding name.

Finally go to the Data tab and select your month column and select the **Sort by Column** option and sort it using the new created column.

Answer (score 0):

Create a support table for month name and month number .
That support table will be static and it has Month name and month number(better create in excel and copy it into power bi instead creating a calculated column)
In my case my it will be based on fiscal year.

[[image: Image shows the data created in excel]

Then Sort that support table month name with month number.
Join the month name of support table with month name of your main table .
Drag the month column from support table instead of main table into your Graph.
Thats it.
If its still not sorted then click on graph and sort it based on month name.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution is to create a column in the same table with an IF or SWITCH statement for each month and sort your MonthName by your MonthNumber.

Code below:

```
Month_Num = SWITCH(TRUE,
[Month] = "Jan",
1,
[Month] = "Feb",
2,
[Month] = "Mar",
3,
[Month] = "Apr",
4,
[Month] = "May",
5,
[Month] = "Jun",
6,
[Month] = "Jul",
7,
[Month] = "Aug",
8,
[Month] = "Sep",
9,
[Month] = "Oct",
10,
[Month] = "Nov",
11,
[Month] = "Dec",
12)
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to Data tab in power bi, Select the column that you need to select and click on the **Sort by Column** and select the column need to be used for sorting (see below pic, In this case month name is being sorted based on the Month of the Year column)

[image]

Comment: I know this one, but there is no date table in my dataset. So, it is creating problem there.